Calculating profitability of short term appartment investment (mortgaged) to avoid renting
Having some issues trying to calculate the profitability of a given rental real estate investment.
Currently, I am using the following:
Property sell price - tax payable - sales fees - interest repayments - operating expenses + rental income - remaining principal on loan.
My question, should I also be deducting my initial deposit and any principal repayments to calculate the final profit of the investment?

Do you already own the property and are converting it to a rental, or are you buying the property? What do you mean avoid renting?

Profit = money out - money in. Totality of your proceeds from the investment minus totality of moneys put into the investment. For different purposes (taxes, for example) it may be a bit more nuanced. So whats your goal here?

Also, if you are taking about buying vs. renting, the question is usually least cost; you only get a profitability answer if you define how you will be investing the difference between rental costs and purchase costs, and if you believe you can make a reasonably accurate prediction of what the property will sell for when you want to move elsewhere.
